# jQuery $.submit and files not working in IE and FF

Tags: php, jquery

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_FILES)){
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $_FILES['file']['type'];
        echo "</pre>";
        return;
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autoUpLoad(){
        $("#txtHint").html("<center><img src='include/images/loader.gif' />Reading selected file...</center>");
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#file").change(function(){
                $("#myForm").submit(function(data){
                    $("#txtHint").html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
<form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id = "file" onchange='autoUpLoad()'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
<div id="txtHint">
    test
</div>
```

The above code is not working and I am not sure what is wrong here? It works only if I remove these lines:

```
function(data){
    $("#txtHint").html(data);
}
```

It just doesn't allow me to return data to `txtHint`. Can anyone explain to me how to make it work?

Comment: i don't understand about this tag . ** <? php **

Comment: Hameed is for jquery to return process data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding a submit event, not fire it.

`.submit()` method with a callback as parameter is used to bind submit event, without parameter to fire the submit event.

You should do something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myForm").submit(function (data) {
        $("#txtHint").html(data);
    });
    $("#file").change(function () {
        $("#myForm").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: But the result does not appear in div txtHint. Everything just looks like reload

Comment: @JonathanChan `.submit` just fire the submit event, and the page will be reload, this is not ajax.

Comment: Oh! Is there any ajax function which can solve my problem? I really have hard time learning ajax jquery...

Comment: @JonathanChan Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery?

Comment: or is there a way to use $.post to send a file?

Comment: @JonathanChan IE7 doest not support html5, you could not use ajax method to upload file.

Comment: Found a solution finally
Using this ajax form instead
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

function autoUpLoad(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
         var options = {
            target:'#txtHint'
            };
            $('#file').change(function() {
            $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit(options);
                return false;
                });
        });
    }